# Convert multiple string to a list in python

Tags: python, string, list, spotipy

I want to get the name of the song from a Spotify playlist for which I am using spotipy library when I print the output it all comes at once I want to get the single name at a time

CODE:

```
for track in sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_link)["items"]:    
    track_name = track["track"]["name"]
    print(track_name)
```

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KA2h.png)

Comment: This doesn't make any sense; you already get it one line at a time

Comment: Put text in the question itself as **text**, not a link to an image.  Make a [mcve].

Comment: @mkrieger1 I want to slice the output

Comment: Do you mean that you want to append the song titles to a list in the loop?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes!

Comment: Why don't you do it?

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: When i try to slice it it print first letter of every title

Comment: Have you tried creating a new list and using its `append` method? It's unclear to me why you slice something when you want to append a value to a list.

Comment: Use a list comprehension: `titles = [track["track"]["name"] for track in sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_link)["items"]]`

Comment: @Barmar can you post this comment as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted

Comment: This is basic language instruction, not worth an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is that you want to add the text of each line to the list

```
my_list = []
for track in sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_link)["items"]:    
    track_name = track["track"]["name"]
    my_list.append(track_name)
print(my_list)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).